# What is the least positive integer $n$ for which $|\sin(n)-\sin(n^{\circ})|<0.005$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, absolute-value, integers

What is the least positive integer $n$ for which $|\sin(n)-\sin(n^{\circ})|<0.005$?

(That is the difference between sine of $n$ radians and sine of $n$ degrees is less than $0.005$)

My attempt:

- $\sin(n^{\circ})=\sin(\frac{n\pi}{180})$
- $\sin(A)-\sin(B)=2\sin(\frac{A-B}{2})\cos(\frac{A+B}{2})$

Putting $A=n$, and $B=\frac{n\pi}{180}$, the given inequality becomes;

$$|2\sin(\frac{n-\frac{n\pi}{180}}{2})\cos(\frac{n+\frac{n\pi}{180}}{2})|<0.005$$

Simplifying, we get;

$$|\sin(\frac{n(180-\pi)}{360})\cos(\frac{n(180-\pi)}{360})|<0.0025$$

Substituting $u=\frac{n(180-\pi)}{360}$, we get;

$\sin(u)\cos(u)<0.0025$

Expanding both sine and cosine, we get:

$(u-\frac{u^3}{6}+\dots)(1-\frac{u^2}{2}+\dots)<0.0025$

or

$u-\frac{u^3}{2}-\frac{u^3}{6}+\frac{u^5}{12}-\dots<0.0025$

I stuck here to find $u$. Otherwise, by finding $u$, I can solve for $n$ since $n=\frac{360u}{180-\pi}$ and I will round the result.

---

Using Microsoft Excel, I found that $n=176$

---

I do not know if my approach is right. If right, how to solve for $u$. If wrong, how to solve this problem:

> What is the least positive integer $n$ for which
>   $|\sin(n)-\sin(n^{\circ})|<0.005$?

Comment: I presume that by $n^{\circ}$ you mean $n$ degrees, so $\sin(n^{\circ})$ is the same thing as $\sin(\frac{\pi}{180}n)$. You should explain that in your post

Comment: Yes,, that is $n$ degrees. Is not that well-known notation? Should I explain it in the post?

Comment: Yes, I think you should explain even though it's well-known, because the ${}^{\circ}$ is so small and almost invisible on many screens.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy , ok dear , I will edit the post. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: How did the two different arguments suddenly become equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t:=\dfrac{\pi}{180}$ and $\epsilon:=0.005$.  We want to find the smallest integer $n>0$ such that $\big|\sin(n)-\sin(nt)\big|<\epsilon$.  That is,
$$2\,\Biggl|\sin\left(\frac{n(1-t)}{2}\right)\Biggr|\,\Biggl|\cos\left(\frac{n(1+t)}{2}\right)\Biggr|<\epsilon\,.$$
This shows that either 
$$\Biggl|\sin\left(\frac{n(1-t)}{2}\right)\Biggr|<\delta\text{ or }\Biggl|\cos\left(\frac{n(1+t)}{2}\right)\Biggr|<\delta\,,\tag{*}$$
where $\delta:=\sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}=0.05$.  Hence, there exists an integer $k>0$ such that
$$\left|\frac{n\left(1-(-1)^kt\right)}{2}-\frac{k\pi}{2}\right|<\text{ArcSin}(\delta)\,.$$
Let $d:=2\,\text{ArcSin}(\delta)\approx2\delta=0.01$.  Then,
$$n\in I_k:=\left(\frac{k\pi- d}{\left(1-(-1)^k\,t\right)},\frac{k\pi+d}{\left(1-(-1)^k\,t\right)}\right)\,.$$
Therefore, you have to only look for integers $k>0$ such that $I_k$ contains an integer $n_k$, and check whether the requirement $\big|\sin(n)-\sin(nt)\big|<\epsilon$ is satisfied when $n=n_k$.  Using a computer search from $k=1,2,\ldots$, we get that $k=57$ yields our smallest $n$, which is $176$.  The search is not too bad.  For the majority of cases, $I_k$ does not contain an integer.

However, you can also make a guess using the continued fractions of $\dfrac{\pi}{1-t}$ and $\dfrac{\pi}{1+t}$.  The continued fractions are, respectively,
$$\dfrac{\pi}{1-t}=3+\frac{1}{5+\frac{1}{15+\frac{1}{1+\ddots}}}\text{ and }\dfrac{\pi}{1+t}=3+\frac{1}{11+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\ddots}}}\,.$$
The sequences of convergents are, respectively, $$\left\{3,\frac{16}{5},\frac{243}{76},\frac{259}{81},\ldots\right\}\text{ and }\left\{3,\frac{34}{11},\frac{71}{23},\frac{176}{57},\ldots\right\}\,.$$
The value of $\dfrac{n}{k}$ should be one of the convergents above.  The smallest $n$ which works and can be obtained by this method comes from the fraction $\dfrac{176}{57}$, giving the smallest value of $n$ to be $176$.  The reason that this method works is due to the fact that, for a real number $r$, if $p$ and $q$ are integers such that $q>0$, $\gcd(p,q)=1$, and $\dfrac{p}{q}$ is a convergent of $r$, then $\dfrac{p}{q}$ is a better estimate of $r$ than any rational number of the form $\dfrac{a}{b}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $0<b\leq q$, i.e.,
$$\left|r-\dfrac{p}{q}\right|\leq \left|r-\dfrac{a}{b}\right|\,,$$
with the equality case $(a,b)=(p,q)$.  You even have a stronger inequality
$$|rq-p|\leq |rb-a|$$
where the equality holds iff $(a,b)=(p,q)$.

Interestingly, it is possible to find a positive integer $n$ such that both inequalities in (*) hold.  (For $n=176$, for example, only the right inequality with cosine is true.) The smallest $n$ that this happens is $n=2430$ ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Select%5BTable%5B%7Bn%2CN%5BAbs%5B%281-Pi%2F180%29%2FPi*n-Floor%5B%281-Pi%2F180%29%2FPi*n%2B0.5%5D%5D%5D%2CN%5BAbs%5B%281%2BPi%2F180%29%2FPi*n-Floor%5B%281%2BPi%2F180%29%2FPi*n%2B0.5%5D%5D%5D%7D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10000%7D%5D%2CMax%5B%23%5B%5B2%5D%5D%2C%23%5B%5B3%5D%5D%5D%3C0.01%26%5D) is how I searched for it), where
$$\left|\sin\left(\frac{n(1-t)}{2}\right)\right|\approx 0.010959\approx\left|\cos\left(\frac{n(1+t)}{2}\right)\right|\,.$$
In fact,
$$\sin\left(\frac{n(1-t)}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{n(1+t)}{2}\right)\approx 8.869\times 10^{-14}$$
for $n=2430$.  I am not sure what is so special about $n=2430$ as both  the sine and cosine values are so close to one another.  Especially, the next value of $n$ that makes both inequalities in (*) hold does not do the same thing, i.e., when $n=7111$, 
$$\left|\sin\left(\frac{n(1-t)}{2}\right)\right|\approx 0.00621\text{ but }\left|\cos\left(\frac{n(1+t)}{2}\right)\right|\approx 0.01124\,.$$

Comment: Interestingly, $k=\left\lfloor\dfrac1t\right\rfloor$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire  Do you think it is a coincidence or is there a deeper meaning?  I think it is just a coincidence.

Comment: I cannot see anything meaningful yet. Although $n(1+t)\approx k\pi$ assuming $k$ odd, and relaxing the floor operation, $n\approx\frac{180}{1+\pi/180}\implies\lfloor n\rfloor=176$ as you have got. Why this is optimal is also currently beyond my understanding.